# Get ASP.NET identity in Powershell

Tags: asp.net, powershell

To setup RSA encryption of a config file, there needs to be a grant access to the ASP.NET identity to access the RSA container. I set it up based on the instructions here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Where it consists of creating an identity.aspx file with the following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
%>
```

How can this be obtained via powershell instead of the aspx file?

Comment: Instead of a page (.aspx), you should expose it as a generic handler (.ashx).

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell syntax for dereferencing static members is a little different than in `C#`, so that would be:

```
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
```